# Excel index formula with text as reference no VBA no Add-on CLOSE file dynamic range

Tags: excel, indexing, path

I need to get cell content from another specific cell in a close file using index only.
I understand that dealing with closed file is possible using index. i don't want the VBA or add-on option, please.

When I write the path by myself:

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\EXE\Export_10_2017.xls]Transactions'!A1:E1000,7,1)
```

it works.

But when I try to insert the path and filename as a reference to a cell that contains the path and filename, it doesn't work:

```
A1=INDEX(K12,1,1)
K12="'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\EXE\[Export_10_2017.xls]Transactions'!"
```

I tried some variants with splitting the name in several cell or use `TEXT` function, `CONCATENATE` and even just with " and &....

appreciate your help for that issue.

Comment: Try `A1=INDEX(INDIRECT(K12),1,1)`

Comment: Whoops, forgot that INDIRECT won't work with a closed sheet. Scrub that idea.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without VBA or an add-in. Looks like you'll have to keep the filepath within the index formula. Or if you've got Excel 2016 then you can use PowerQuery (aka "Get & Transform") to pull the value from the closed workbook. (You can also download PowerQuery as an add-in for Excel 2010 or 2013 from Microsoft).

Comment: thank you, i tried without double quotes, but it doesn't help.

Comment: unfortunately i will use PowerQuery... just wondering, why it is not possible if INDEX can work with closed files, and all other formulas can use this kind of reference inside the formula...THANK YOU !